# Understanding of Netty internals

Tags: java, netty

In my understanding of Netty's, incoming message passed to eventLoop(only one eventLoop, one thread). Next, EventLoop doesn't process it, but pass it to ExecutorService(it holds multiple threads in pool) for execution.

All this happens with the help of NIO. EventLoop waits for incoming messages and pass it by selectors, keys, channels etc.

Am I right?

Netty 4 is used

Comment: Could you provide some code to illustrate your problem ?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton No code available, Im read about Netty's internals

Comment: Could you please include in your question which version of netty you're using (keep in mind that libraries can change over time, so this may become invalid for later versions), maybe also include which class / method you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `Netty` uses the `EvenLoopGroup`s for handeling incoming and outgoing data as well as incoming connections.
That shouln't be so interesting when you start using Netty as the way the data goes through different classes. When a message is inbound the first interfacce you can intercept it is the decoder (`ByteToMessageDecoder`) where your encrypted `ByteBuf` is available. Then its making its way through the handler (`ChannelInboundHandler`).